# node.js / express app failing with error that a variable hasn't been defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

Trying to learn how node.js and express work.  I've been able to query data from my mongo database... and now I'm playing around trying to understand how to pass data between my router code and my views.

I have this code in my locations.js file in my routes folder:

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    console.log('Inside GET method');
    loc.find(function (err, locations) {
    if (err) return next(err);
        //    res.json(locations);  THIS WORKS.
        //    res.render('index', {loc_data:res.json(locations)});  THIS FAILS
           res.render('index', {loc_data:locations}); //FAILS
  });
});
```

And this is what my index.ejs file looks like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app>
  <head>
    <title>test</title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='/stylesheets/style.css' />
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>location data</h1>
    <p><%= loc_data %></p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Currently, the code is failing with the error : loc_data is not defined
I'm learning by reverse engineering a demo app that someone else created. 
So i'm probably missing something really basic.

Any tips would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Doh!  So simple.  Realized that after making code changes... I wasn't restarting the application.  I just expected it to refresh automatically.  So now I'm making my code changes... rerunning "node app.js" (missed this step before) and then refreshing my browser and it's fine.